# ZFC-universe without non-standard natural numbers?

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers

I assume, that we all have (beside any set-thoretic background) a good intuition, what "the usual natural numbers" are, although we seem not to be able to describe them precisely.

So having said this: If we have a ZFC-universe $U$ it makes sense to seperate the members of $\omega_U$ absolutely into standard "numbers" (those members of $\omega_U$, which represent a "usual natural number") and non-standard "numbers".

Furthermore I want to assume the consistency of ZFC.

My Question is:

**Does any ZFC-Universe $U$ "exist", for which $\omega_U$ does not contain non-standard "numbers"?**

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "non-standard 'numbers'"?

Comment: Those members of $\omega_U$ which do not represent a "usual natural number". For example $\emptyset_U$ represents the "usual natural number" 0, $\{\emptyset\}_U$ represents the "usual natural number" 1, $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}_U$ represents the "usual natural" number 2 and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you assume there is a "true" universe of sets, the answer is yes, but of course this is not a mathematical argument. If you refer to *set models*, the assumption that there is such a model (an *$\omega$-model*) is strictly stronger than the assumption that set theory is consistent, which is itself not provable in set theory (by the second incompleteness theorem).

Recall that $\mathrm{Con}(T)$ is an arithmetic (in fact $\Pi^0_1$) statement whenever $T$ is recursively enumerable; for example, $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is the statement "no $n$ codes a formal proof of $0=1$ from the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$". If there is a model of set theory, this statement is true (in the standard natural numbers), and therefore any $\omega$-model of set theory is also a model of $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$, of $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}))$, etc, so the consistency strength of "$\mathsf{ZFC}+$ There is an $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$" not only is higher than that of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, it is in fact *much* higher. This theory cannot prove its own consistency, so (if there are $\omega$-models at all) there are $\omega$-models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ where no set model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is an $\omega$-model.

The nicest models of set theory not only are $\omega$-models, they are in fact *well-founded* (sometimes called *$\beta$-models*). Any well-founded model of set theory is also a model of "there is an $\omega$-model" (this follows from Mostowski's absoluteness theorem, a statement of which you can see in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/33022/6085) on MO), so assuming the existence of well-founded models is a further (significant) jump in consistency strength. That said, most set theorists routinely assume (believe?) there are such models, and much more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful answer! Why is the answer yes, if there is a "true" universe $U$ of sets? I naively think $U$ could contain non-standard numbers.

Comment: The "true universe" is well-founded, and its natural numbers are the standard numbers, that is part of what being "the true" model entails. (It also contains ill-founded models, and models with non-standard natural numbers.) Again, this is of course not a formal claim.

Comment: A model $M$ of ZFC being an $\omega$-model means $\omega_M$ satisfying all arithmetic truth? Then T="ZFC+There is an $\omega$-model of ZFC" does not seem to be recursively enumerable. So what does Con(T) mean?

Comment: See [here](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/woodins-proof-of-the-second-incompleteness-theorem-for-set-theory/), though that presentation currently has an error, and I should be posting soon a corrected version. (The correction is simple, though: Rather than requiring  that $P$ is a property of models, and hereditary, we must require that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves both these facts.)

Comment: Being an $\omega$-model means that $\omega_M$ is isomorphic to the standard $\omega$ (so, in particular, the model is correct about arithmetic truth, but this requirement is stronger). The consistency of this theory can be expressed semantically, saying that there is a model of it, and the claim is that, if there are $\omega$-models at all, then there is an $\omega$-model inside of which there are no $\omega$-models. (Note $T$ is r.e., being expressible within set theory, where "the standard $\omega$" just means $\omega$, what we are claiming is stronger than just second incompleteness).

Comment: What does "the standard $\omega$" mean? If it is $\omega_U$ for the universe $U$ with $M\in U$ (interpretation 1), why do we know $U$ is correct about arithmetic truth? If "the standard $\omega$" is what I call "the (intuitive, not set-theoretical) usual natural numbers" (interpretation 2), we even cannot express $M$ being an $\omega$-model using a formula, can we?

Comment: It is interpretation 1, of course, and correctness etc are defined internally within the model $U$. Naturally $U$ could be wrong with respect to arithmetic truth (whatever than means), but that is irrelevant as we are only comparing arithmetic statements in $M$ and in $U$.